# Hover with line to wave

Tags: css, animation, hover

I'm trying to create this hover:

[image: hover style]

This is what I have done. Is there a way without an image? Also is it possible the line to be animated from streight line to wave line?

```css
    body {
      align-items: center;
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    a {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #453886;
      color: #453886;
      padding-bottom: .25em;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9632/squiggle.svg");
      background-position: bottom;
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
      background-size: 20%;
      border-bottom: 0;
      padding-bottom: .3em;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
```

Comment: Would you check the photo ? , Because it won't open.

Comment: I think there is option with JS and SVG files but you need to check how to do it. If you google something like `animating with js and svg` should give you the answer.

Comment: pseudo and border-radius could partially simuate this : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mdbLRoe

Answer (score 0):

CSS has `text-decoration-style` property.
check here: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/wavy-unerline/

```css
body {
      align-items: center;
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    a {
      color: #453886;
      padding-bottom: .25em;
      text-decoration:underline ;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      text-decoration:underline wavy;
      
    }
```

```html
<a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
```